# Proof of Jensen's inequality - why is this progression valid

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

I'm reading a proof of Jensen's inequality in the following version:
Let $f: I\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ be a convex function defined on an interval $I$. Then:

$$\forall{x_1,...,x_n\in I}\space\forall_{t_1,...,t_n\in [0;1], t_1+...+t_n=1}f(\sum_{i=1}^nt_ix_i)\leq\sum_{i=1}^nt_if(x_i)$$

The proof starts as follows:

$$f(\sum_{i=1}^nt_ix_i)=f(t_nx_n+(1-t_n)\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{t_ix_i}{1-t_n})\leq t_nf(x_n)+(1-t_n)f(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{t_ix_i}{1-t_n})$$

I don't understand the last progression. Why are we allowed to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use induction and the inequality: $f(tx+(1-t)y) \leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$. The first equation creates a bridge for you to reach the final inequality.

Note that: $r=\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{t_jx_j}{1-t_n} = \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{t_j}{t_1+t_2+\cdots + t_{j-1}}\cdot x_j$. Then $\text{min}(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n-1})\leq r \leq \text{max}(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_{n-1})\Rightarrow r \in I.$

Comment: How do we know that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{t_ix_i}{1-t_n}$ is in $I$?

Comment: See my edit to show that $r \in I$